# Converting XY Coordinates to Projected Local Coordinate System using QGIS

Tags: qgis, coordinate-system, qgis-3, qgis-processing

I am working in QGIS 3.14, and I have created a shapefile with X and Y coordinates that has COVID testing centers in Maryland and the EPSG is 4386.  I want to do a buffer algorithm on these sites to see the locations that are at least 500 meters from a current site.  However, I can only do distance in degrees and there is a warning that says I should convert to a projected local coordinate system.

How would I do so?

When I have tried to do this in the past, the points have completely disappeared from the map.

Comment: If you do not wish to change the CRS, in the buffer distance use 0.0045 degrees = 500m  https://www.usna.edu/Users/oceano/pguth/md_help/html/approx_equivalents.htm#:~:text=0.001%C2%B0%20%3D111%20m,(7%20decimals%2C%20cm%20accuracy)

Answer (score 2):

Try [Reproject Layer](https://docs.qgis.org/3.16/en/docs/user_manual/processing_algs/qgis/vectorgeneral.html#qgisreprojectlayer):

> Reprojects a vector layer in a different CRS. The reprojected layer
> will have the same features and attributes of the input layer.

Pick a  coordinate reference system which have meters as units

Comment: If I'm using WGS 84, what would be one I can use that has meters as units?

Comment: I'm not sure, maybe [32618](https://epsg.io/32618). It depends on what you are going to do, your required accuracy etc.

Answer (score 2):

Rightclick on layer / export / save features as... and than select a CRS